# Going to the Google Chrome website crashes Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: crash

So I just wanted to check out the website for Google Chrome, but when I start loading the page in firefox, Ubuntu crashes to the login screen and won't let me back on my desktop.

Comment: Are you running the most current version (48) of Firefox? Have you tried turning off Firefox extensions, and seeing if you can access the web site?

Comment: I am running Firefox 48 and I disabled all my extensions and going to the google chrome website still crashes Ubuntu for me. This all started when I was trying to get Netflix to work for me. Netflix said it needed Silverlight to run, so I installed Pipelight and Netflix still doesn't run for me, and sometimes Netflix would crash Ubuntu. I tried using Chromium and I still had the same problem, so I decided to check out the Google Chrome website to see if there was an official version of Chrome that would run on Ubuntu, but the website itself crashes Ubuntu for me!

Comment: Using Firefox/Pipelight to view Netflix is tricky. Google Chrome can run Netflix directly without any tricks. Can you access other web sites using Firefox without any problem? Can you watch videos on YouTube?

Comment: ps: I would uninstall Pipelight, and then see if Firefox can go to the Chrome website without crashing.

Comment: I can visit other websites without any problems, including youtube. How do I uninstall pipelight?

Comment: Open Synaptic from the Dash. Type pipelight in the search box. When it finds it, right-click on the name and select Mark fo complete removal, then click the Apply button.

Comment: ps: from the login screen, choose Guest, and try Firefox from there.

Comment: I removed Pipelight, but the Google Chrome website still crashes Ubuntu for me. I tried using a guest session, which doesn't have Adblock; the Google advertisement page for Google Chrome opens fine with no problems, but the non-advertisement page still crashes Ubuntu. I had Netflix working earlier with Pipelight, I am going to reinstall Pipelight.

Comment: Give me the URL's that you are using for the 2? Google sites, and I'll try them here.

Comment: This website for chrome crashes Ubuntu for me: https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjrr8CT47fOAhVmImMKHQDDCSgQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fchrome%2F&usg=AFQjCNG0QgKiMLSAPPY5lW5p_yF04bpFmA&bvm=bv.129389765,d.cGc

This website doesn't crash: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?brand=CHBD&gclid=CIujyqLjt84CFUGSfgodZrMG4g

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the two websites that you mentioned in our previous discussion, and the first one, the one that crashes Firefox, works fine for me. But, I noticed that it's got some kind of strange Flash? moving graphic thingie on that page.

This leads me to believe that you may be running an old Flash v11.2 in your Firefox. So, I suggest that you use the second URL to download and install Chrome, then go to Synaptic and install pepperflash. This will allow Firefox to use the newer v21 Flash that is embedded with Chrome. Then I'll be that you can go back to that crashing URL and it'll be fine.

Keep me posted. Cheers, Al

Comment: I did what you said but Ubuntu still crashes when I go to that first website, both in Firefox and Google Chrome. Also Ubuntu crashes when I open the Google Chrome menu (three dotted lines on the top-right side of the screen). Also with Firefox I am unable to add hyperlinks to my emails using Microsoft Outlook.

Comment: I tried going to that website using Chromium, and it works there, but if I open the three-dotted menu button it crashes like it does in Google Chrome.

Comment: So in Firefox, if you look at add-ons/extensions/Shockwave Flash, it shows v21, yes? Well, I'm at a loss. You may just have to reinstall Ubuntu to solve the problem. Sorry 'bout that. Cheers, Al

Comment: I have Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202. It says it is up to date though.

Comment: No, after installing pepperflash (for Firefox), and Chrome (to get the latest Flash), you should show v21. So that may still be your problem. Flash v11.2 is the last version ever made for Linux (unless you've got Chrome and pepperflash installed). You can image the difference between v11.2 and v21. I don't remember if you have to manually uninstall v11.2 first. Of course, I still don't know why Chromium/Chrome is crashing for you. The Ubuntu reinstall may still be in your future.